# ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d is displayed differently when exported to pdf

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I am using ngx-charts on my angular 7 application.
I am creating a dashboard, and some of my cards contain ngx-charts.
My problem is, that when I export it either using jspdf this way:

```
            var data = document.getElementById('dashboardArea');
            html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
                // Few necessary setting options  
                var imgWidth = 208;
                var pageHeight = 295;
                var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
                var heightLeft = imgHeight;
    
                const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
                let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
                var position = 0;
                pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
                pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF
```

Or getting the inner html this way:

```
    var data = document.getElementById('dashboardArea');
    var innerhtml = data.innerHTML;
```

and sending it to the server side, using all sort of pdf creators, I get the same result. the chart area is black.

[image: my chart inside the browser]
[image: same chart when exported in all kind of tools to pdf]

The ngx-line-chart displays normally on the PDF.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tx Tal.

Comment: Have you tried this([A way to change the color for axis and ticks](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/540)) ?

Answer (score 1):

The same issue happen to me, then I use domtoImage instead of html2Canvas.

```
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById(chartId)).then(function(dataUrl) {
  const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(dataUrl);
  pdf.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 20, 30, imgProps.width, imgProps.height);
  pdf.save(fileName);
}
```

This won't cause any issue of black bg.